# Reading images and extract label from path with TensorFlow

Tags: python, tensorflow, image-recognition

I am trying to read images files with tensorflow and get the labels from the path as follows:

```
import tensorflow as tf

filename_queue = tf.train.string_input_producer(
                                 tf.matching_files(
                                    tf.constant(["./positive_images/*.jpg",
                                                "./negative_images/*.jpg"])))

image_reader = tf.WholeFileReader()

file_name, image_file = image_reader.read(filename_queue)
label = tf.map_fn(lambda x: "positive" in x, file_name)
image = tf.image.decode_jpeg(image_file, channels=1)

with tf.Session() as sess:
    # Required to get the filename matching to run.
    tf.global_variables_initializer()

    # Coordinate the loading of image files.
    coord = tf.train.Coordinator()
    threads = tf.train.start_queue_runners(coord=coord)
    filename1 = sess.run([label])
    print(filename1)

    image_tensor = sess.run([image])
    print(image_tensor)

    coord.request_stop()
    coord.join(threads)
```

However I get the error:

```
in map_fn raise ValueError("elems must be a 1+ dimensional Tensor, not a scalar")
ValueError: elems must be a 1+ dimensional Tensor, not a scalar
```

Reading the images seems to work, but the filename can not be parsed correctly. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: The error message you got clearly shows you where the problem is: the 2nd argument to tf.map_fn() should be a 1-D (or more) tensor and you are passing the return from WholeFileReader.read(), which is a 'string scalar Tensor' (zero-D). I am not an expert in tensorflow, but it looks like the read() function returns one (name, content) pair per invocation rather than producing two sequences, as you might have expected.

Comment: `read()` indeed returns two scalar tensors. I would highly recommend using `tf.data` APIs. They are much cleaner and generally faster. You can find an example for reading images here: https://www.tensorflow.org/programmers_guide/datasets#decoding_image_data_and_resizing_it

Comment: I solved it with the following command:

`X_train_images_decoded = tf.map_fn(lambda x: tf.image.decode_image(tf.read_file(x), channels=1), X_path, dtype= tf.uint8`

X_path is a 1d Tensor with the Paths to the images that I created with the function os.walk